# Positive and negative numbers with ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, input, joptionpane

How do I seprate positive and negative numbers? I have this code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

        int num=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many numbers?"));
        for (int i=0 ; i < num ; i++) {
            al.add(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What numbers?")));
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say I want to add 5 numbers. `-2, -7, 8, 4, -1`

I need the output to be `Positive = 8, 4`  and `Negative = -2, -7, -1`

Comment: keep two arrays?  Sort them?  Now sure exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I just want to (if possible) seprate the negatives and positives

Comment: You could easily separate numbers using the build-in function Math.signum(double)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Java 8, you can use stream to separate them easily:

```
List<Integer> positive = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> negative = new ArrayList<>();
al.stream().forEach(i -> (i < 0 ? negative : positive).add(i));
System.out.println(positive);
System.out.println(negative);
```

You have two lists one containing positive, the other containing negative.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the output of the arrays, a loop through the array one time will work easily and quickly enough, even for large arrays. With that, you can use StringBuilder objects to handle your output.

```
StringBuilder pos = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder neg = new StringBuilder();

pos.append("Positive = ");
neg.append("Negative = ");

//note that 0 will be considered positive
for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
    if (al.get(i) >= 0) {
        pos.append(al.get(i) + ", ");
    } else {
        neg.append(al.get(i) + ", ");
    }
}

//handles the extra "," at end of strings
pos.deleteCharAt(pos.length() - 2);
neg.deleteCharAt(neg.length() - 2);

System.out.println(pos.toString() + " and " + neg.toString());
```

If you would like to do anything more complex than simple output, I'd suggest you use `if` logic to assign individual integers to two separate arrays.

Another note, you should probably tell the ArrayList what type of object to expect:

```
ArrayList<int> al = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Please don't take the code above for law... I don't have an IDE available right now, so it was written in the SO editor ^^

Answer (score 0):

Solution of your problem:

```
public class Test {

    public static void printValues(ArrayList<Integer> list)
    {
        StringBuilder positive = new StringBuilder("Positive = ");
        StringBuilder negative = new StringBuilder("Negative = ");
        for (Integer i : list)
        {
            if (i >= 0)
            {
                positive.append(i).append(", ");
            }
            else
            {
                negative.append(i).append(", ");
            }
        }
        positive.delete(positive.length() - 2, positive.length());
        negative.delete(negative.length() - 2, negative.length());
        System.out.println(positive.toString());
        System.out.println(negative.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

        int num=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many numbers?"));
        for (int i=0 ; i < num ; i++) {
            al.add(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What numbers?")));       
        }
        printValues(al);
    }
}
```

Or you can use lambda expressions and streams

```
public class Test {

    public static void printValues(ArrayList<Integer> list)
    {
        StringBuilder positive = new StringBuilder("Positive = ");
        StringBuilder negative = new StringBuilder("Negative = ");

        list.stream().forEach(i -> (i < 0 ? negative : positive).append(i).append(", "));

        positive.delete(positive.length() - 2, positive.length());
        negative.delete(negative.length() - 2, negative.length());
        System.out.println(positive.toString());
        System.out.println(negative.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

        int num=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many numbers?"));
        for (int i=0 ; i < num ; i++) {
            al.add(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What numbers?")));
        }
        printValues(al);
    }
}
```